# How to see http statuscode of resources loaded in browser via javascript console?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I want to see the http statuscode of the files loaded in browser like .css files, .js files programatically via javascript(Something to execute from console). 
I can see the the required information from firebug(Net tab), but i want these info programatically

Comment: use jquery [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and look for option `statusCode`

Comment: i need status code of each resource/file(say .css or .js)